# generating soap files for tr069 client, help required

Tags: web-services, soap, gsoap

I am using gsoap for implementing the soap stack of my tr069 client completely written in C language.

The xsd file i am using is cwmp-1-2.xsd from broadbanforum.
In cwmp-1-2.xsd , The ParameterValueStruct is defined as :

```
 <xs:complexType name="ParameterValueStruct">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="Name">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="256"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="Value" type="xs:anySimpleType"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
```

"Value" element is polymorphic type and so, "value" must show the actual data type of the parameter.
e.g. `<Value xsi:type="xsd:integer">` or `<Value xsi:type="xsd:boolean">` depending on the parameter type it has to show.

But it is only showing `<Value xsi:type="xsd:anySimpleType">0</Value>` for all cases.

I am not able to find any solution as to how I will be able to implement the polymorphic attribute of the element using C.

Do I have to modify typemap.dat or dom.h ??